# Typeahead suggestion not showing on input field area

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, typeahead.js

I am using **Typeahead** JS for auto suggestion.Firebug response the result fine but result does not showing on input field area.Anyone help pls?

Html code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/typeahead.js/0.9.3/typeahead.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input#username').typeahead({
                name: 'username',
                remote: 'search.php?key=%QUERY',
                minLength: 1, // send AJAX request only after user type in at least 3 characters
                limit: 12, // limit to show only 10 results
                highlight: true
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="searchmark" class=""  method="POST">
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" class="typeahead-devs"  placeholder="Type name">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Search">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

php code

```
<?php
include_once '../Controller/DbHelper.php';
$db = new DbHelper();

//$key= $_GET['key'];
$key = $_REQUEST['key'];

// do query 
$query = "SELECT user_name FROM national_certificate WHERE  user_name LIKE :user_name";
$stmt = $db->con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':user_name', '%' . $key . '%');
$stmt->execute();

foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    $result[] = $row["user_name"];
}
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Firebug response result  (if i type ra)

> ["Rasel mahmud","Sourav paul","Rashed","Samrat","Rahman"]

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input#username').typeahead({
        name: '#username',
        remote: 'search.php?key=%QUERY',
        minLength: 1, // send AJAX request only after user type in at least 3 characters
        limit: 12, // limit to show only 10 results
        highlight: true
    });
});
```

please try this,  '#username' make sure you have the id name with '#'.